# How select default option of dynamically added dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a string like from server using jquery:

```
<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option>
```

then I create a dropdown within a div:

```
$.get('server.php', function(data) {
    $('#mydiv').html('<select id="mysel" name="mysel">'+data+'</select>');
});
```

problem is that when I create this, I want to select one option so:

```
$("#mysel").val("3");
```

but doesn't work! if I add an alert before calling this line, then this works!

```
alert('test');
$("#mysel").val("3");
```

can not find what is problem.

NOTE: I can not change the way I get data from server.

Comment: Well the edited question code works as expected for me. Which browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: I assume the line `$("#mysel").val("3");` is outside of the `$.get() {}`? The response from `$.get` is _asynchronous_ so the `$("#mysel").val("3");` executes before the HTML `<option>` elements are added. Adding the `alert()` delays the execution long enough for the `<option>` to exist in that scenario. Solution: move `$("#mysel").val("3");` inside the `$.get() {}` body.

Comment: @andyb: Probably. He should just post all the relevant code together. But I think that's exactly what is causing this.

Comment: @andyb yes! that is it, you are correct :D

Comment: Added my comment as an answer. I'll leave it up to you whether you want to just delete the whole question or accept an answer.

Comment: @exim, check out my solution when you get a chance, especially the last block. It's good to avoid unnecessary dom manipulation.

Comment: @andyb I selected your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the line `$("#mysel").val("3");` is outside of the `$.get() {}`...

The response from `$.get` is *asynchronous* so the `$("#mysel").val("3");` executes *before* the HTML `<option>` elements are added.

Adding the `alert()` delays the execution long enough for the `<option>` to exist in that scenario.

The simplest solution here is to move the `$("#mysel").val("3");` inside the `$.get() {}` body.

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing the right `id`. Your select's id is mysel and you are trying to select an option in mydiv. Change

```
$("#mydiv").val("3");
```

to

```
$("#mysel").val("3");
```

Comment: try this `setTimeout('$("#mysel").val("3")', 1);`

Comment: Should avoid trying to hack something using a timeout, you rely on something happening within an arbitrary time and the user can see an item changing after being appended to the dom. This is what callbacks are for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `get()`'s callback. You can use the `success` one you already have:

```
$.get('server.php', function(data) {
    $('#mydiv').html('<select id="mysel" name="mysel">'+data+'</select>');
    $("#mysel").val("3");
});
```

or you can use `done`:

```
$.get('server.php', function(data) {
    $('#mydiv').html('<select id="mysel" name="mysel">'+data+'</select>');
}).done( function() { "#mysel").val("3") });
```

**Edit:** actually, rather than adding something to the dom and then modifying it, it would be better to modify before inserting.

```
$.get('server.php', function(data) {
    $mysel = $('<select id="mysel" name="mysel">'+data+'</select>').val("3");
    $("#mydiv").append($mysel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selectedIndex property:

```
document.getElementById("mySel").selectedIndex = 3;
```

Comment: I have not access to data that provide index values.

Comment: Then: `document.getElementById('mySel').value = 3;`

Comment: Other than a slight boost in performance, `document.getElementById('mySel').value = 3;` wouldn't do anything different than `$("#mysel").val("3");`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#mysel option:selected").val("3");
```

And if you want to set the text try:

```
$( "#mysel option:selected" ).text("3");
```

But you must declare this after your dropdown is created in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.get('server.php',{dataType:'text/html'}, function(data) {
         $('#mydiv').html('<select id="mysel" name="mysel">'+data+'</select>');
         $("#mysel").val("3");
    })
});
```

> try the above code;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select#mysel option").each(function() { 
       if($(this).text() == '2')
          this.selected = true;
   });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that `mysel` will not be there on `ready()`. Also, there is no need to add select qualifiers on top of an id as id's are unique. Use `#mysel` rather than `select#mysel`.